how to configure ARR reverse proxy and URL Rewrite for iis docker container?
I've run the iis docker container in my local windows server on port 250 and the container ip is (192.168.10.1) . I've point the local server public ip (31.56.#.#) to this domain name "testvault.info". and i host web site inside my above mentioned iis docker container. now need to point the above mentioned domain name to web site inside the docker iis container so how to configure arr reverse proxy for this scenario and point domain name to web site inside docker container.

Docker IIS Container: Ensure the container is running and accessible locally at http://192.168.10.1:250.
Public IP & Domain:
The domain (testvault.info) is pointed to your server's public IP (31.56.#.#).
IIS with ARR Installed:
ARR (Application Request Routing) must be installed on the IIS instance running on the host server.
For the configuration of ARR you can help you with this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module

Thanks for your words, can you give me some tips how to use ARR in this above scenario, I have faced this problem for more than 20 days, your words will help me in my upcoming moves. @Hadrien Valet

Do you have a dockerfile or docker-compose about your work and the version of your container IIS ? Otherwise, I found this github repository which could probably help you : https://github.com/vegarberget/docker-iis-arr/tree/master
